Can an argument that has objectively true premises be valid if the conclusion is subjectively true?
I've had this idea floating in my head all day. Let's say for example I have the following two premises:


I have been depressed lately
My friends have been acting weird around me lately.


And conclude that


Everyone hates me.


If the premises are objectively true, but the conclusion is only subjectively true (true to me until proven otherwise) can the argument still be considered valid?

Faulty generalization.

depressed, weird and hate are not objective terms at all. Even depressedwhich apparently has a strict clinical definition, really is highly subjective.

@Stewart You can rewrite #1 more objectively: "I have been diagnosed as clinically depressed." But the rest is indeed subjective.

@Barmar Important to keep in mind that, although the fact of the diagnosis is objective (the therapist either did or did not add this diagnosis to the patient’s chart), there is a great deal of subjectivity in both what clinical standards were chosen for that diagnosis and in the therapist’s judgment that the patient meets those standards. Not that either is completely subjective, either; both are informed by research and training, of course. But at the end of the day, much is still subjective in this field.

@KRyan Of course. Practically everything in psychology and psychiatry is subjective -- you need to go to neurology to get something close to objective, but that takes you farther from behavior so it's not useful for arguments like this.

(@Barmar Yeah, I suspected that you very well knew everything I had to add, I just felt like it was an important point to have here for anyone else reading.)

@Barmar Which brings into the equation the fact that psychiatry does not have objective tests for these things. It's all the subjective opinion of the psychiatrist. So now you have two subjective viewpoints to deal with.

@Stewart Two? Whose was the first opinion before the psychiatrist? But didn't I already say "everything in psychiatry is subjective"?

@Barmar The person who is allegedly depressed is subjective opinion #1. The psychiatrist is subjective opinion #2.  If you did say, "everything in psychiatry is subjective", then I agree with you, but I missed where you said it :)

@Stewart Right. I essentially shifted the subjectivity from the patient ("I'm depressed") to the psychiatrist ("I've been diagnosed as depressed"). Of course, the patient could also be schizophrenic and there's no actual psychiatrist. So much comes down to whether we can trust our senses and opinions.

The standard conception of "validity" relates only to the form of the argument, irrespective of any actual truth value.
Under that conception, an argument is valid only if the conclusion logically follows from the truth of the premises.
You example is not a valid argument in that sense. You have simply listed three unconnected propositions.
And Conifold says:

Informal validity is a loose notion, but to the extent that this argument supports a conclusion it is an objective one: "I am likely to think that everybody hates me". Without the added part, the depression premise is completely irrelevant. And if we go from the second premise only then "everybody hates me" is not subjective, it is just very weakly supported, even "my friends hate me" would be a leap.



Can an argument that has objectively true premises be valid if the conclusion is subjectively true?

First, if you believe the conclusion, you don't need the argument to convince you that it is true.
Second, an argument is logically valid if the conclusion follows necessarily from the premises. Whether the premises and the conclusion are actually true is irrelevant. Whether you believe they are true or not is also irrelevant.
Being objectively and/or subjectively true is also irrelevant to logical validity. However, the subject matter of the premises do determine the subject matter of the conclusion.
Your argument:

I have been depressed lately
My friends have been acting weird around me lately.
(so) Everyone hates me.

Each one of these clauses sounds subjective to me!
This argument itself is of course not valid. It is a non sequitur. The conclusion simply doesn't follow from the premises. The premises (together) do not imply the conclusion--unless you and your friends were the only people left in the whole universe!
Example of a valid argument mixing objective and subjective truths:

I am a human being (objectively true);
I feel in a bad mood (subjective truth);
So, there is at the moment at least one human being who feels he is in a bad mood.

Argument with subjective truths only:

I am happy;
I am hungry;
Therefore, I am both happy and hungry.

I can't make up any argument with objective premises and a subjective conclusion, but the possibility of a logically valid argument depends ultimately on what exactly we think subjective truths and objective truths are and therefore the relation between the two.

While having depression might incline people to infer that "my friends are acting weird around me, therefore everyone hates me", what you've presented here isn't a valid argument.
This has been pointed out by other answers, but validity has nothing to do with the truth of the premises. Validity is solely determined by whether you correctly applied the rules of whatever logical system you're following.
In general, logical systems aim to preserve some properties of the premises. Classical logic "preserves" truth when applied correctly: if you correctly apply the inference rules to true premises, any conclusions you draw will also be true. (There are other kinds of logical systems too that preserve other properties, such as justification).
That being said, the argument posed above isn't valid because it doesn't correctly apply any inference rules. There's not even a clear connection between any of the three statements. It's unclear how "I've been depressed" is related in any way, shape, or form to "everyone hates me." Similarly, "my friends have been acting weird around me" is not clearly connected to "everyone hates me" for the following reasons:

The statement is about your friends in particular, but the conclusion is about people "in general."
There are all kinds of reasons that people can "act weird" - it's not clearly connected to feeling hatred.


If the premises are objectively true...

Others have pointed this out, but it's not clear to me that the premises you present are objectively true.

...but the conclusion is only subjectively true (true to me until proven otherwise)...

I'm not sure what "true to me until proven otherwise" could possibly mean. If something is true, then it's true for everyone. It's not like everyone has their "private copy" of reality.
Also, if a statement is later disproven, it wasn't true for anyone - it was just a false statement that some people happened to believe. For example, people used to believe that the sun revolved around the earth. At no point was this statement true to anyone: it was just a false statement that was widely accepted at one time but is now known to be untrue.

can the argument still be considered valid?

No, for the reasons listed above.

You ask:

Can an argument that has objectively true premises be valid if the conclusion is subjectively true?

No. A deduction has to have a universally valid conclusion if one has strictly objective premises. Let's look to claims in the deductive reasoning article in WP. It says:

Deductive logic studies under what conditions an argument is valid. According to the semantic approach, an argument is valid if there is no possible interpretation of the argument whereby its premises are true and its conclusion is false. The syntactic approach, by contrast, focuses on rules of inference, that is, schemas of drawing a conclusion from a set of premises based only on their logical form.

So, under a syntactic interpretation, clearly it's a meaningless question because the symbols themselves are devoid of content. Ostensibly, the symbols themselves are unambiguous and objective. Thus, the symbols themselves can be inferred mechanically without an appeal to meaning.
Under a semantic interpretation, we see that the description hinges on the notion of 'interpretation'. Thus, the question of subjective and objective meaning becomes somewhat moot, because the question of the validity is a function of "truth being necessary". By what criteria can we say the truth of a conclusion must be necessary given some premises?
This notion of semantic necessity would seem to involve value judgement. It would seem, if you recognize a hard fact-value distinction, that if you have two objective statements, you wouldn't be able to draw a value-laden inference. For instance:

P1. Socrates is in the kitchen.
P2. The kitchen is in the house.
C. Socrates is a great cook.

In fact, it would seem impossible to assert a value on the basis of two objective facts. (And I challenge you to do so.) On the other hand, it follows necessarily from our understanding of the physical world:

P1. Socrates is in the kitchen.
P2. The kitchen is in the house.
C. Socrates is in the house.

Thus, it would seem by definition, two truly objective premises would require a universal conclusion, that is, a conclusion that holds up in all times and places. (For instance, what is true of Socrates, the kitchen, and the house is valid everywhere on earth and not just Greece. Thus, if a semantically valid deduction with two objective premises were made, it would be a contradiction that the inference was in some way true or false dependent on one's thinking since a deduction by definition has a necessarily true conclusion.
It might be helpful, however, to know that objectivity is often viewed through the lens of intersubjectivity, instead. Thus, there are no truly objective facts, but rather facts where two agents are subjectively in agreement. Objectivity can also be undermined by the use of attacking the is-ought or fact-value distinction. A standard meter, for instance, is based on an operation definition which is in fact a preference of sorts.
